# How to transfer User To A Chrome Link?

Tags: c#

I want user to go on a link when he clicks on a button. I use 6.0 .Net Framework

When I click on button its says system cannot find specified file

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://example.com");
}
```

Comment: Also, for the record, ".Net Framework" stops at 4.8.1. It's just called ".Net 6".

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", "http://google.com");
```